# Having trouble parsing a file in C

Tags: c, linux, file-io

I am trying to write a program that automatically opens a google classroom link of the class I have two minutes before it starts.
So far I have decided to have a tsv file with three columns: Time, Subject, Gmeet link respectively.
somewhat like this:

```
[1]
11:15   CD  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify
14:00   SGD https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify
15:05   SGD https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify

[2]
09:00   AI  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify
```

The numbers in the square boxes correspond to the day of the week.
So what I am planning to do is to store the day's schedule in an array of size 9 as I can have classes at 9 different timeslots at any given day, with the link of each class being at index[hour - 9]. So the first class at 9 am will be at index zero and the timeslots that are empty will have null as their value.

This is what the code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

const char FILE_NAME[] = "schedule.txt";
const int CLASSES = 9;

int main()
{
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm *local = localtime(&now);

    FILE *file = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r"); /* Input file */

    char line[100];
    int hour;
    char *min;
    char *sub;
    char *link;
    /* char current_day = local->tm_wday; */
    char current_day = 1;
    char *sched[CLASSES];

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file: \"%s\"\n", FILE_NAME);
        exit(8);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < CLASSES; ++i)
        sched[i] = NULL;

    char dayfound = 0;
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        if ((line[0] == '[' && atoi(&line[1]) == current_day)) {
            dayfound = 1;
            continue;
        }
        if (dayfound && line[0] == '\n') {
            dayfound = 0;
            break;
        }
        if (dayfound) {
            hour = atoi(strtok(line, ":"));
            min = strtok(NULL, "\t");
            sub = strtok(NULL, "\t");
            link = strtok(NULL, "\t");
            sched[hour - 9] = link;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < CLASSES; ++i) {
        if (sched[i] != NULL)
            printf("%s", sched[i]);
    }


    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason the value of the first class I have that day is getting overwritten by the empty string, and I am only getting the links of the other two classes.

This is the output:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify
```

As you can see the first link for CD is missing.
Can anyone point out why this is happening?

Comment: Error messages should be informative and written to stderr.  Try `if (file == NULL) { perror(FILE_NAME); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Comment: `link = strtok(NULL, "\t"); sched[hour - 9] = link;` is writing a pointer to a buffer location into your array: that buffer *will get overwritten* by the next `fgets()` - advise using `strdup()` for example `sched[hour - 9] = strdup(link);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading into the same `line` string for every line of the file. `strtok()` returns a pointer into that string. So all your `link` values point to the same string.

You should make a copy of `link` when assigning it to `sched[hour-9]`:

```
sched[hour - 9] = strdup(link);
```

Or you could make `sched` a 2-dimensional array and use `strcpy()`

```
char sched[CLASSES][100];
...
strcpy(sched[hour - 9], link);
```